# Postgresql: Select value difference between values in Integer column

Tags: postgresql

My question is simple. Say I have the following column:

```
order_in_group
integer
------
1
2
3
5
6
9
```

I would like the query result to be the difference between the current and next values **which is bigger then 1**:

```
value1   value2   difference
integer  integer  integer
-------  -------  -------
3        5        2
6        9        3
```

Any help will be great.

Comment: Are the values always in numeric order, or how would you know the order to process them in?

Comment: Yes, @JoachimIsaksson, these are point (geometry) registrations from an app which logs a user's route. That's why the order will always be from 1 and up to a number (end of route). What I need to check here is if some data chunk has not been delivered correctly to the server thus the missing elements in the order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to just use `LAG` to get the previous row to compare with;

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT order_in_group value2,
     LAG(order_in_group) OVER (ORDER BY order_in_group) value1
  FROM mytable
)
SELECT value1, value2, value2-value1 difference
FROM cte
WHERE value2-value1 > 1;
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
with q(i) as (
    select unnest(array[1,2,3,5,6,9])
    )
select prev, curr, curr- prev diff
from (
    select i curr, lag(i) over (order by i) prev
    from q
    ) s
where curr > prev+ 1;

 prev | curr | diff 
------+------+------
    3 |    5 |    2
    6 |    9 |    3
(2 rows)
```

Comment: Thanks fro your input.